# TestFlight ItunesConnect Export Compliance Information Pop up not hiding when pressing the Start Internal Testing button

Tags: ios, testflight

In simple words, I have created a new build 2.4.0 and put it to testflight. After clicking on the missing compliance warning sign and the pop where it shows (Title : Export Complainace Information) and then the no radio button and lastly clicking the Start Internal testing button. So now the build 2.4.0 is active for testflight. (So far so good). But now i want my earlier builds to be in testflight as well. But builds (eg 1.6.8) when i proceed with same steps as above the pop where it shows (Title : Export Complainace Information) is not hiding after clicking on the Start Internal testing button. 
Note: I had previously made the build 1.6.8 to testflight testing and it was working fine.
**So what can be done about it. Is this a apple server issue or some kind of rule. ???**

Comment: First of all, build number should always be incremented

Comment: @PiyushMathur new build is 2.4.0 . Previous ones are .. 1.6.8 ...

Comment: If your app has no warning[Missing Compliance]  against build number  in Testflight & showing in testing status ,you are good to go.Even i faced this issue once few days back for beta testing but moving same build for AppStore review didn't throw any error.

Answer (score 3):

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

This stands for a Boolean value equal to NO. This will silence export compliance pop up.

Add it to your info.plist

It means the app uses no encryption, or only exempt encryption. 
If your app uses encryption and is not exempt, you must set this value to YES/true.

Comment: Then please frame your question properly